# Security works correctly in unit test but not when deployed in application server (weblogic)

Tags: spring, rest, oauth, resttemplate, oauth-1.0a

Can anyone tell why this didn't work? The code works great when I run it from my unit tests. Security gets setup perfectly and our service works great just like I expect.

However, when I deployed it to our application server (weblogic), my service fails every time because my tokens are not getting setup. I got it working by setting up the tokens every time my `send(final ServiceAPInvoice invoice)` method gets called.

My question is why does the tokens not get setup by my constructor when this is deployed in our Weblogic environment? What causes this issue? OAuthSecurityContextHolder is a static class. Is that playing into my issue? Will I still run into issues if I setup the tokens each time my send method is called? I haven't noticed any issues yet but have not done any load testing

I am using Spring's OAuthRestTemplate (1.0) and I have non-expiring tokens that I need to setup.

Here is where the magic happens. I had to rename the code slightly to make it generic so hopefully I don't have any typos:

```
public class ServiceRestTemplate {

private final OAuthRestTemplate serviceOAuthRestTemplate;

private final String apUri;

private final String arUri;

private final String tokenValue;

private final String tokenSecret;

public ServiceRestTemplate(final OAuthRestTemplate serviceOAuthRestTemplate,
                          final String apUri,
                          final String arUri,
                          final String tokenValue,
                          final String tokenSecret) {
    this.serviceOAuthRestTemplate = serviceOAuthRestTemplate;
    this.apUri = apUri;
    this.arUri = arUri;
    this.tokenSecret = tokenSecret;
    this.tokenValue = tokenValue;
    setContext(tokenValue, tokenSecret); // I expected this to be enough to setup my tokens 1 time
}

private void setContext(final String tokenValue, final String tokenSecret) {
    final OAuthConsumerToken accessToken = new OAuthConsumerToken();
    accessToken.setAccessToken(true);
    accessToken.setResourceId(serviceOAuthRestTemplate.getResource().getId());
    accessToken.setValue(tokenValue);
    accessToken.setSecret(tokenSecret);

    final OAuthSecurityContextImpl securityContext = new OAuthSecurityContextImpl();
    if (securityContext.getAccessTokens() == null) {
        securityContext.setAccessTokens(new HashMap<String, OAuthConsumerToken>());
    }
    if (!securityContext.getAccessTokens().containsKey(accessToken.getResourceId())) {
        securityContext.getAccessTokens().put(accessToken.getResourceId(), accessToken);
    }

    OAuthSecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
}

@Override
public ServiceWebResponse send(final ServiceAPInvoice invoice) {
    setContext(this.tokenValue, this.tokenSecret); // This line of code is the workaround to fixed my issue. 
    final ServiceWebResponse serviceResponse = serviceOAuthRestTemplate.postForObject(apUri,
                                                                                   invoice,
                                                                               ServiceWebResponse.class);
    return serviceResponse;
}
}
```